# fix undefined variable in native wp files

Tags: plugins, variables

I had a trouble with installing new plugins as I would get error message "Something went wrong" when trying to search for any plugin. When I enabled `wp_debug` i got error saying

```
Notice: Undefined variable: errno in /usr/chroot/apache2.4/usr/local/apache2.4/htdocs/domain-name/wp-includes/Requests/Transport/fsockopen.php on line 137
```

Is there some single file which I could replace to have that variable defined correctly, or something else I can do?

Comment: The issue isn't in WordPress. Somewhere you have code in a theme or plugin that is doing something incorrectly. Deactivate themes and plugins one by one until the issue goes away. Then you've found the culprit.

Comment: Jacob is correct.  Assuming you have not edited the WP core files, the cause of that error is in a plugin or theme.